# How can I get queues counts in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

I'm studying Vulkan from LunarG's tutorial codes.
In `03-init_device.cpp` of the tutorial, it just get the queue family's count, then assumed that it has only one queue and create the logical device. Sample codes as follows:

```
int sample_main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sample_info info = {};
    init_global_layer_properties(info);
    init_instance(info, "vulkansamples_device");

    init_enumerate_device(info);

    /* VULKAN_KEY_START */

    VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo queue_info = {};

    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(info.gpus[0],
                                             &info.queue_family_count, NULL);
    assert(info.queue_family_count >= 1);

    info.queue_props.resize(info.queue_family_count);
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(
        info.gpus[0], &info.queue_family_count, info.queue_props.data());
    assert(info.queue_family_count >= 1);

    bool found = false;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < info.queue_family_count; i++) {
        if (info.queue_props[i].queueFlags & VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT) {
            queue_info.queueFamilyIndex = i;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    assert(found);
    assert(info.queue_family_count >= 1);

    float queue_priorities[1] = {0.0};
    queue_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO;
    queue_info.pNext = NULL;
    queue_info.queueCount = 1;
    queue_info.pQueuePriorities = queue_priorities;

    VkDeviceCreateInfo device_info = {};
    device_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
    device_info.pNext = NULL;
    device_info.queueCreateInfoCount = 1;
    device_info.pQueueCreateInfos = &queue_info;
    device_info.enabledExtensionCount = 0;
    device_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = NULL;
    device_info.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    device_info.ppEnabledLayerNames = NULL;
    device_info.pEnabledFeatures = NULL;

    VkDevice device;
    VkResult U_ASSERT_ONLY res =
        vkCreateDevice(info.gpus[0], &device_info, NULL, &device);
    assert(res == VK_SUCCESS);

    vkDestroyDevice(device, NULL);

    /* VULKAN_KEY_END */

    destroy_instance(info);

    return 0;
}
```

Well, is `queue family counts` the same thing as `queue count`?
Or there's something wrong with this sample code?

Answer (score 3):

Each device has several families of queues each with their own count.

For example a device may have a family that with one queue can only do transfers (typically used for achieving optimal pcie bus usage) and a family with multiple queues for rendering.

When requesting queues you can request less queues than are available. So 1 is always a valid count.

Comment: To complete this answer, `VkQueueFamilyProperties::queueCount` contains the number of queues for a given queue family.

Comment: @ratchet: Do you means that sample codes just acts with discretion by fill 1 into `queue_info.queueCount` instead `info.queue_props[queue_info.queueFamilyIndex].queueCount`?

Comment: @naive231yeah if you only need one queue then there is no need to ask for more.